# IPN listener for PayPal in Meteor app

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, paypal, paypal-ipn

I stuck with one problem.
I`m trying integrate PayPal button with meteor app.   But for full functionality i need to handle with IPN.
Because i have to know at least transaction status.
I already have business account and i turned on IPN on path:

```
    http://domein.com/ipn
```

I tried use [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/), but it doesn't help too.
I spend two days and still can't find anything helpful.
Maybe someone know how to implement IPN listener in meteor app?

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: Update for Meteor 1.3+**

I published a package that vastly simplifies the process.  The package is [planefy:paypal-ipn-listener](https://atmospherejs.com/planefy/paypal-ipn-listener).

First, install then package:

```
$ meteor add planefy:paypal-ipn-listener
```

Then, in server code:

```
import { IpnListener } from 'meteor/planefy:paypal-ipn-listener';

const listener = new IpnListener({ 
   path: '/mypath', 
   allow_sandbox: true // in development
});

listener.onVerified((err, ipn) => console.log(ipn));
listener.onError((err) => console.log(err));
```

See the [readme](https://atmospherejs.com/planefy/paypal-ipn-listener) for more options.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I did a lot of head scratching trying to figure this out too.

First, add the following packages, if you don't already have them.

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
meteor add meteorhacks:picker
```

If you are using iron:router, then you actually don't need need meteorhacks:picker (See update at bottom)

Create a package.json in your application root (if it doesn't already exist), and add the following to tell meteorhacks:npm which npm packages need to be installed:

```
{
  "paypal-ipn" : "3.0.0",
  "body-parser": "1.14.1",
}
```

In server code, configure Picker to properly parse JSON requests/responses:

```
const bodyParser = Meteor.npmRequire('body-parser');
Picker.middleware(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
Picker.middleware(bodyParser.json());
```

Also in server code, define a Picker route to handle incoming IPN messages

```
Picker.route('/ipn', function(params, req, res, next) {

  res.writeHead(200);

  const ipn = Meteor.npmRequire("paypal-ipn");

  // create a wrapped version of the verify function so that 
  // we can verify synchronously
  const wrappedVerify = Async.wrap(ipn,"verify");

  let verified = false;

  // only handle POSTs
    if (req.method === "POST") {

    // PayPal expects you to immeditately verify the IPN 
    // so do that first before further processing:
        try {

            //second argument is optional, and you'll want to remove for production environments
            verified = wrappedVerify(req.body, {"allow_sandbox" : true});

        } catch (err) {

            // do something with error

        }

        if (verified === 'VERIFIED') {

            let payment = req.body;

            // do stuff with payment 
        }

    }
  res.end();

});
```

Update:  If you are using iron:router, you don't need to use Picker.  You can just define a server only router directly with iron:router, like so:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('ipn', {
        path: '/ipn',
        where: 'server',
        action: function() {
            var ipn = Meteor.npmRequire("paypal-ipn");
            var wrappedVerify = Async.wrap(ipn, "verify");

            var request = this.request;
            var verified;

            if (request.method !== 'POST') {

              this.next();

            } else {

              try {
                verified = wrappedVerify(request.body, {"allow_sandbox" : true});
              } catch (error) {
                //do something with error
              }

              if (verified === "VERIFIED") {
                var payment = request.body;
                //do something with payment
              }

              this.next();
            }

        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: i use iron-router, can i install and use both packages?

Comment: you should be able to.  Picker is just for server side routes.  You could also just define a server-only route using iron router, I'll update my answer

Comment: i think I am close to resolve this problem) just a couple question. i tried IPN Simulator but it always sho me that. If we define ipn path on server side, how paypal will be able to do something with this path?

Comment: PayPal is sending the POST request directly to your server, that's why we define the route there

Comment: @bluebird i used your code for IPN listener but when i test the it, new tab opens telling me to define client side route, can you check my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059753/how-to-define-client-side-route

Comment: Wow, you saved me with the Picker route and middle ware.  You have the only posted code on how to do this on the internet!  Thank you!  By the way, It would be even more complete if you updated this with the new npm imports features that Meteor 1.3+ takes advantage of.

Comment: thanks @Aaron. I have update the example for Meteor 1.3